# Why does this if never runs

Tags: javascript, angular

What I am trying to achieve is:
 - first the callback runs and
 - `this.auth.javaAuthToken`, which is a property in another file, gets initialized to the value of the token.
 - after that, this function is called: `return this.auth.getUserFiles();`

If I do this:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<any> {
   let token = null;
    this.auth.emailListCleaningUserDetail().subscribe((res: any)=>{
    token = res.body.data.access_token;
    token = this.auth.javaAuthToken;
     return this.auth.getUserFiles();
  });
```

Then I get an error:

> function must return a value

So I have written the code below to check if the token exists.  If so, then I call the function and return.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<any> {
   let token = null;
    this.auth.UserDetail().subscribe((res: any)=>{
    token = res.body.data.access_token;
    token = this.auth.javaAuthToken;
    console.log(token);
    console.log('inside fun');  
  });
    if(token) {
      console.log('inside if outside fun');
      this.auth.javaAuthToken = token;
      return this.auth.getUserFiles();
    }
    console.log('outside if and fun')
  }
}
```

When I run the program,
- First `outside if and fun` is printed,
- then the token is printed, and
- then `inside fun` gets printed.

Comment: hi, if an answer helped, please mark the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Its quite simple, when you are trying to access token (when you return your result), the result is not yet available.
In async functions you either have to await the value or subscribe to the event.

If you subscribe to the event, you can only access the value inside the subscription.

```html
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<any> {
   let token = null;
    this.auth.UserDetail().subscribe((res: any)=>{
    token = res.body.data.access_token;
    token = this.auth.javaAuthToken;
    console.log(token);
    console.log('inside fun');  
    
    // This is called when you receive your result which can be later as the code below as this is async

  });

// token is always null because its declared as null before
// when this code runs, there is no result of your Service yet
    if(token) {
      console.log('inside if outside fun');
      this.auth.javaAuthToken = token;
      return this.auth.getUserFiles();
    }
    console.log('this runs right after the code before but the result is not available yet')
  }
}
```

im wondering if this is async too:

```
this.auth.getUserFiles();
```

You could then do something like this

```html
LoadUserData = async event => {

    var token = null;
    var userfiles = null;
    try {
        var response = await this.auth.UserDetail()
        if (response.data != null) {
            token = response.data.access_token;        
            console.log('Receiving result: '+JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('ERROR: '+error)
    }

    try {
          var responseUserFiles = await this.auth.getUserFiles();
          if (responseUserFiles.data != null) {
              // do something with your userfiles
              userfiles = responseUserFiles.data;
              console.log('Receiving result: '+JSON.stringify(responseUserFiles.data));
          }
      } catch (error) {
          console.log('ERROR: '+error)
    }

    // Here you can return what you want, userfiles  or token
    return userfiles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<any> {
   let token = null;
    this.auth.UserDetail().subscribe((res: any)=>{
    token = res.body.data.access_token;
    token = this.auth.javaAuthToken;
    console.log(token);
    console.log('inside fun');  

    if(token) {
      console.log('inside if outside fun');
      this.auth.javaAuthToken = token;
      return this.auth.getUserFiles();
    }

 });
    console.log('outside if and fun')
  }
}
```

Comment: `return this.auth.getUserFiles();` must be returned outside the callback otherwise it gives an error function must return ...